# How do I choose which card I want my opponent to discard?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

When I cast [Distress](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=236908), I am supposed to be able to choose which card the opposing player discards.

However, I have not found any reliable way of making the program discard the card I want it to. When you enlarge a card there is no Choose Card tag.

When a card is merely highlighted, the program seems to pick another one at random.

Is there a way to reliably choose a card to be discarded?

Comment: just to check, you aren't trying to pick a land to discard are you?

Comment: No, I am trying to pick one of his non-land cards, but almost invariably the game discards a different one.

Comment: Frankly, the MtG games have always been hit and miss at allowing the player to choose important things. Up to the most recent version, you had to let the PC choose which lands to tap, making it very awkward to play 2 things in one turn if you were playing with more than one colour.

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be due to there being two "highlights" when performing this type of card selection in Magic 2014. There is a orange highlight for the card currently being looked at, and there is a white highlight for the card that has been selected. The first card you look at becomes selected, but if you then look at other cards the first card is still selected (i.e. has a white highlight). You have to click/tap the selected card to deselect it, and then you can select the card you actually want.